# Alternatives to doc2vec?

Tags: python, nlp, data, word-embeddings, data-science-model

What are some alternatives to the doc2vec embedding model? I.e models that convert paragraphs/documents into vectors, not just models that take the mean/sum of the word embeddings of each word in the document.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your target task. If you are to classify documents, then e.g. fastText has it's own approach and there are other classification techniques, not strictly generating embeddings, like LSA / LDA (using topic modelling) or word mover distance.